# запрос MySQL сразу к двум полям таблицы

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Есть запрос:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE title LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY $sorting",$link);
```

Как сделать так, чтобы искал в поле title + в text?

Comment: Слышали про `OR`? Вот тут оно как раз используется.

Comment: Не как не могу использовать((

Answer (score 1):

1. ```
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE title LIKE '%$search%' OR text LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY $sorting",$link);
   ```
2. **Выбросьте навсегда** mysql-функции. Они морально устарели и больше не используются. Если вы их используете, значит у вас уже устаревший php5.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте PDO! И биндите переменные)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE title LIKE %$search% OR title LIKE %$search% ORDER BY $sorting";
$result = $db->prepare($sql);
$result->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, функции `mysql_*` в PHP не рекомендуются к использованию (deprecated). Вместо них нужно использовать MySQLi.

Потом, запрос с вставкой переменных в строку чреват уязвимостью к SQL-инъекциям. Сферически в вакууме считается, что нужно привязывать (binding) конкретные значения как аргументы к запросу (в самом запросе указываются параметры). Но это палка о двух концах, поскольку результаты таких запросов не кэшируются MySQL. На выделенном сервере (включая V[DP]S) можно получить хорошую производительность, используя запросы без параметров.

> Как сделать так, чтобы искал в поле title + в text?

Можно использовать LIKE и OR, но считается, что [полнотекстовые ключи (fulltext index)](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Fulltext_Search.html), которые заодно могут объединять несколько полей, работают быстрее.

Далее, это уже не совсем по теме вопроса, но есть максимально простое и достаточно эффективное решение, которым можно значительно увеличить эффективность поиска - [стемминг](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3).

Answer (score 0):

**Ответ:**

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `news` WHERE `title` LIKE '%$search%' OR `text` LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY $sorting", $link);
```

**MYSQL** -  устарел, рекомендую изучить [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php) и использовать [**bindValue**](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) дабы избежать [**SQL инъекции**](https://habr.com/post/130826/), ибо в вашем запросе это возможно.